# How to change a usernames password to secret without deleting username

Tags: cisco

```
Router1(config)#username admin privilege 15 algorithm-type scrypt secret xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ERROR: Can not have both a user password and a user secret.
Please choose one or the other.
Router1(config)#
```

I then try to take out the password using the "no" command

```
Router1(config)#no username admin password ?
  <cr>  <cr>
Router1(config)#no username admin password
This operation will remove all username related configurations with same name.Do you want to continue? [confirm]
```

Is there a way to change this from password level 7 to secret level 9 without deleting the username. I'm worried about the other related configurations unless this is a none issue i should not worry about

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's generally fine to proceed.  It's just a warning saying it will remove any references you're making to the username, like if you have custom roles defined, or you have custom attributes defined for that account.

Comment: That's just a warning. Review the configuration and look for some reference for that username. When you clear this doubt , change the password

Comment: @OrlandoGaetano when you mean some reference, do you mean running something like ```show run | i admin``` ?